# Why is arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF losing layer symbology?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.2, pdf, arcpy

When exporting a map it does not export the symbology within the data frame.  I am using the code snippet below.

```
>>> myMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:/USERS/NISUSER/DESKTOP/mxd_map.mxd")
>>> arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(myMap, "C:/AgTech/agtech.pdf")
```

The first image is what is located in the data frame:
[image: Data Frame]

[image: Resultant PDF]

I am expecting the 2nd image to be identical to the 1st, but as a PDF.  The symbology changes in the process somehow.

Comment: Do you have any layers with transparency turned on?

Comment: What ArcGIS for Desktop version are you using?  Does your map have only one data frame?

Comment: @ RyanDalton, I just changed the transparency and no luck. @PolyGeo, I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and one data frame.

Comment: I just tested this using what I believe to be the same steps and ArcGIS version as you, and it worked fine.  Consequently, you may be wise to edit your Question to include the exact steps taken since starting ArcMap to author a simple test map, and then the total Python code run to demonstrate the problem on that test map.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not saved the MXD since updating the symbology, or used the arcpy.save () function in your code, it might be the answer here.